# Docker ports not mapping from Docker's tutorial

Tags: docker, networking, port, dockerfile

I am working through the tutorial on [Docker's website](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app) and am having trouble getting the ports to map like described.

I am exposing the port in my Dockerfile with `EXPOSE 80` and running `docker run -p 4000:80 containername` to start the application. The code is copied directly from the tutorial, but for completeness sake the flask server starts with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

When I go to localhost:4000 in my browser or curl it I get that the site can't be reached.

Comment: Are you using docker-machine ?

Comment: Nope, just using what's outlined in that tutorial. First time using Docker, so I don't know all the tooling around it yet.

Comment: What os are you using ?

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12

Comment: if you use the cmd docker ps do you see the container running and the mapping in port.

Comment: I see it up and mapped, yes.

Comment: hmm try to acces with 0.0.0.0:4000 or 127.0.0.1:4000 if it work check your hostfile in /private/etc/hosts

Comment: Tried both of those and there's nothing extra in my hosts file. I am access any other servers that I am running on localhost just fine as well.

Comment: `docker run <container-id> ss -ltn` should **not** see 127.0.0.1

Comment: What is the command that start flask inside that container ?